# Multiple links to a single file on Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

I'm considering making a folder of audio files available via Dropbox and want to create different links to the same folder for distribution. Anyone who gets a link, either in the form of a coupon accompanying a cassette or vinyl record, could then download a digital version by using the unique link.

Is there a way of creating multiple different links so I can also track who has and who hasn't downloaded their copy of the digital album?

And while I'm at it, is there a way of limiting the number of downloads using each link to two or three downloads?

Answer (score 0):

No, Dropbox doesn't offer these features, but we'll consider them feature requests.